# New single after error

Tags: lambda, oauth-2.0, rx-java2

i develop my own download user data flow, and have problem. Buyt first some code, method explanation:

```
loginManager.getAccessToken() //Returns Single<String> where string is my access token
loginManager.getRefreshToken() //Returns Single<String> where string is my refresh token
loginManager.downloadUserAccountData(String accessToken) //Returns Single<String> where string is my json response
loginManager.refreshAccessToken(String refreshToken) //Returns Single<String> where string is new access token
userManager.parseUserJson(String json) //Returns Single<User> where User is my user model
userManager.storeUser(User user) //Returns Completable
```

Currently I doning something like that:

```
Completable getAndStoreUserData = loginManager.getAccessToken()
        .flatMap(loginManager::downloadUserAccountData)
        .flatMap(userManager::parseUserJson)
        .flatMapCompletable(userManager::storeUser);
```

But this does not support, refresh access token and retry download. Server throw `403` when my `accessToken` is not current, so i return error in that case in my function `downloadUserAccountData`

Now i have tried to use `doOnError()` and `onErrorReturn()` but both of this operartors don't met my requirements. This is because `doOnError()` allow only to e.g. display `Log` and dont return anything. `onErrorReturn()` lets me return only value not a `Single<Value>`.

This is pseudocode i trying to achieve:

```
Completable getAndStoreUserData = loginManager.getAccessToken()
        .flatMap(loginManager::downloadUserAccountData)
        .onErrorReturn(error -> loginManager.getRefreshToken()
                .flatMap(loginManager::refreshAccessToken)
                .flatMap(loginManager::downloadUserAccountData)
        .flatMap(userManager::parseUserJson)
        .flatMapCompletable(userManager::storeUser);
```

Any examples appreciated :)

Comment: Do you use retrofit ?

Comment: @Cochi No i don't. I can not use Retrofit in this project :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed, how to do it. As @Cochi proposed i have used `retryWhen()` function. This is very simple example based on `String` for anyone else:

```
String body = null;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Single<String> stringSingle = Single.create(source -> {
                if(body != null) {
                    source.onSuccess(body);
                }
                else {
                    source.onError(new Exception("403"));
                }
            })
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
                if(error.getMessage().contains("403")) {
                    Throwable throwable = refresh().blockingGet();
                    if(throwable == null) {
                        return Flowable.just(new Object());
                    }
                    return Flowable.error(throwable);
                }
                return Flowable.error(error);
            }))
            .flatMap(obj -> Single.just(obj.toString()));
}

public Completable refresh() {
    return Completable.create(source -> {
        try {
            body = "Success";
            source.onComplete();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            source.onError(e);
        }
    });
}
```

And there is full example, using my code:

```
Completable getAndStoreUserData() {}
    Completable getAndStoreUserData = loginManager.getAccessToken()
            .flatMap(loginManager::downloadUserAccountData)
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatmap(this::retryConditionChecker))
            .flatMapCompletable(userManager::storeUser);

    return getAndStoreUserData
}

Publisher<?> retryConditionChecker(Throwable error) {
    if(error.getMessage().contains("403")) {

        Throwable throwable = loginManager.getRefreshToken()
                .flatMap(loginManager::refreshAccessToken)
                .flatMapCompletable(loginManager::replaceAccessToken)
                .blockingGet();

        if(throwable == null) {
            return Flowable.just(new Object());
        }
        return Flowable.error(throwable);
    }
    return Flowable.error(error);
}
```

But biggest problem there is `blockingGet()`. I believe this is very bad solution. Maybe anyone know any better one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `retryWhen`

> Returns an Observable that emits the same values as the source ObservableSource with the exception of an onError. An onError notification from the source will result in the emission of a Throwable item to the ObservableSource provided as an argument to the notificationHandler function. If that ObservableSource calls onComplete or onError then retry will call onComplete or onError on the child subscription. Otherwise, this ObservableSource will resubscribe to the source ObservableSource.

```
    Completable getAndStoreUserData = loginManager.getAccessToken()
            .flatMap(loginManager::downloadUserAccountData)
    .retryWhen(new Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Observable<Throwable> throwableObservable) throws Exception {

                    return throwableObservable.map(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<?> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            if (throwable.getMessage().contains("403")){  // dummy test example
                                return loginManager.getRefreshToken()
                                        .flatMap(loginManager::refreshAccessToken)
                                        .flatMap(loginManager::downloadUserAccountData)
                            }
                            return whatever;
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
   .flatMap(userManager::parseUserJson)
   .flatMapCompletable(userManager::storeUser);
```

[Here](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) some other example.

Sorry for my english and i'm not familiar with the lambda.

Comment: Can you provide simple example even operating on strings, which represent my problem? Currently i don't know how i can use it.

Comment: Yes i will try.